# Reading List<Byte> from specific byte

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `List<Byte>` with 10 values (4,6,9,25,64,31,54,15,98,33) and want to get a `Byte<List>` starting at a specific value/byte for example the value 54 (newbytelist: 54,15,98,33)

```
List<Byte> values;
List<Byte> newbytelist;

foreach (byte item in values.Skip("from value 54"))
{
    newbytelist.Add(item);
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for [`SkipWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549075(v=vs.100).aspx) method:

```
values.SkipWhile(x => x != 54);
```

An alternative using Skip would be:

```
values.Skip(values.IndexOf(54))
```

Comment: Fastest gun in the west!

Comment: Yeah, +1 because I'm new to C# and fairly new to LINQ/lambda and trying to "practice" by racing the pros.  I lost :)